# How to open excel template and save it to another path with pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a simple excel template 
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOPCd.png) with some deferent sheet

and i already has a few dataframe for each sheet with the the same header name
However, i want to write it with this template and save it to another directory.
How can i do that using python and pandas? Or any other solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas deals with only tables not formatting

Use [openpyxl library](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) instead

Comment: thanks, i figure out how to make this approach by using style formating